# Is it possible to set display type per time series in Jira - Rich Filter Time Series?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to add a gadget in a Jira dashboard using the Rich Filter Time Series.

This type of gadget lets me set the display type, so either cumulative total, or period value. But this display type is being set for all time series (lines) in the graph. I want to have a line that's calculated based on its period value, and another line that's calculated as a cumulative total.

Is this possible? Or is there another gadget that would let me do this?